# QTableWidget clearing is slow

Tags: python, qt, pyside, python-3.5

I am using python3.5 and pyside to create a GUI application. I've run into the following problem:

On my GUI, I've got a QTableWidget which I dynamically add Rows and Items to:

```
rowPos = tableWidget.rowCount()
tableWidget.insertRow(rowPos)
        for i in range(numberOfColumns):
            newItem = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(vals[i])
            newItem.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
            tableWidget.setItem(rowPos, i, newItem)
```

Now my problems is that when I want to manage many rows with the QTableWidget, I can't clear it fast anymore. If i execute

```
    tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
```

with as many as ~30.000 rows inserted, the application crashes.

Is there some kind of best practice that says "If you want to display that much then use GUI element XY" or am I just doing it wrong?

I've also tried the clear() method and replacing the whole QTableWidget with an empty one at runtime with no luck or no good results :( Hiding the rows is not an option for me unfortunately.

Thanks a lot! <3

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: If you're dealing with large number of items, you should use custom item model instead of `QTableWidgetItem`. Closest example that I found: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28218882/how-to-insert-and-remove-row-from-model-linked-to-qtableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28218882/how-to-insert-and-remove-row-from-model-linked-to-qtableview)

Comment: Thanks guys, i managed to solve the problem by subclassing QAbstractTableModel and implementing my own model :)